# CSS issue on zooming browser - Element is disappearing from view on zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I have `div` with height **1px** and width **100px**. Now I am zooming my web page from 100% to 80% or less (67% or 50% or 33%). The element is hidden from visible now at certain zoom level. But it is available in DOM structure.

Then when I go to develop menu and change the value of height from "1px" to "2px" or "3px", the element gets appeared in the view.

Please check the following code snippets:

```css
#test1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;      
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
```

Do anyone have idea about this? And can I get fix for this with CSS? That is element to be visible in all the zoom levels.

Note: I am zooming the web page using `ctrl` and `+` or `ctrl` and mouse wheel.

Answer (score 1):

you can change height value for any zoom level

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var zoomLevel = window.devicePixelRatio;
    if(zoomLevel < 0.67 && zoomLevel > 0.3){
     $("#test1").css({ 'height': '3px' });
    }else{
      $("#test1").css({ 'height': '1px' });
    }
  });
```

https://codepen.io/piscu/pen/EboKLX

Comment: Yes. I am expecting solution with CSS.

Comment: also you can use media tag for example
(at)media (max-width:771px){  }